# How to use natural gas mostly sourced from ʟɴɢ on appliances designed only with propane burners?

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering, gas, natural-gas

Given identical pipes, and given in Europe propane from bottles is distributed at 34millibars (G31) and 20millibars for main gas (G20 standard).
**Using the [Wobbe index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wobbe_index), how much natural gas should be compressed in order to reach the level of propane at the G31 standard pressure** ? I’m meaning the aim is to increase gas flow with the same burners.

I don’t care about the heat level : I just don’t want carbon monoxyde for indoor use (blue flame is what is needed). So the question only about using the [Wobbe index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wobbe_index).

Comment: Originally posted on https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/736981/how-to-use-natural-gas-mostly-sourced-from-%ca%9f%c9%b4%c9%a2-on-appliances-designed-only-with?noredirect=1#comment1650771_736981

Comment: If the device is purposely tamperproof, as many portable units are, then just don't do this. It may get connected to propane again in the future, and that would be bad. You may be able to replace an entire burner assembly with one that can only be connected to the alternative gas plumbing. I don't know what the piping standards are in Europe. Note that automatic pressure cutoffs, pilot safety switches, and tip-over switches all have to work properly as well.

Comment: @PhilSweet In terms of prices, bottled gas is high here. I would rather use electricity. Otherwise, it s about appliance without safety cuts when there s no fire. **Otherwise, burners are very specific to the appliance and it s not possible to change them**. Rather than changing the burners, an other way to increase the gas flow which is also used by some furnaces is to increase the gas pressure above the standard level.

Comment: Here's how I would interpret this question: "Can I run propane burners on natural gas if I adjust the input pressure".

Comment: @Drew no but how to do it. The Wobbe Index is designed on purpose and such compressors do exists for industrial ovens instead of home appliances (above 10MWatts).

Answer (score 0):

Many stoves are sold with two sets of jets. Just use the jets appropriate for the gas available.

Also the jet sizes supplied are limited to a given altitude - as ambient air pressure changes

Comment: The problem is portable gas stoves and portable forced air gas heaters are only available with propane/lpg. So conversion required. **I m living at see level**.

Comment: Ahh, if you had specified “portable” then that would have made a difference to the answer, you need to improve your question so others don’t waste time.

Comment: When I say conversion required, it is indeed because equivalence is required. Please trust more peoples. **Please also remove your useless answer so it appears without answers in the question listing in order to attract more peoples**. Except if you find a forced air gas heater directly designed for working with natural gas at 20mbar (G20 standard).

Comment: If the device is purposely tamperproof, as many portable units are, then just don't do this. It may get connected to propane again in the future, and that would be bad. You may be able to replace an entire burner assembly with one that can only be connected to the alternative gas plumbing. I don't know what the piping standards are in Europe. Note that automatic pressure cutoffs, pilot safety switches, and tip-over switches all have to work properly as well.

Comment: @PhilSweet I don t want to modify the devices but the gas.